# MIMIC dataset : How to find time since first admission

Tags: mimic-iii

In the process of creating a survival dataset the time to death after first admission needs to be calculated. For patients who are still alive how can the duration-alive from first admission be calculated. In other words from what date should date of first admit be subtracted.

Answer (score 2):

I will reinterpret your question as "For patients who are still alive, what censor time is appropriate?". The minimum amount of time a patient must survive in order to not have a date of death in the MIMIC-III v1.3 database is 150 days. Most patients are alive for longer: but this is the minimum.